# VB.NET QueryString

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using datagrid and I have a `<asp:TemplateField>` I have passed some parameters in it the code is as follow:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" Text="Download" PostBackUrl='<%#"~/logout.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID")+"&category=mobile"%>'></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have numeric field (ID) which i need to send through URL I have tried to send the String type data and its working fine but while I am sending numeric type (ID) I am facing this error

> Conversion from string "~/logout.aspx?ID=" to type 'Double' is not valid

I know something I need to change in the syntax near `Eval("ID")`. How should I send numeric data in query string?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download">
                <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" Text="Download" PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("~/logout.aspx?ID={0}&category=mobile", Eval("ID")) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: No problem. I think the issue was that the Eval() function doesn't output a string. You were trying to add a string and this value together causing an error. I think an alternative fix may have been to put Eval("ID").toString() but I think String.Format() looks a lot neater :)

Answer (score 2):

The `<%#` syntax should just be used for evaluating a specific data item.  You are trying to build up the entire string in the `<%#` which is not necessary since most of the data is static.

Just a hunch as to why you are getting the error in the `ID` specific scenario is because you have the whole item `string` and `double` information in your binding `<%#` it is using the type of the `Eval` statement to figure out what the whole section should be.  In your case it is looking at the value of `Eval("ID")` and knows it is a `double` and it is then expecting the binded result to be a `double`.  Problem is your concatenating the `string` and the `double` so that wants to return a `string` which is invalid to based on the expected type from the `Eval`.

When your data is sent to the `querystring` it IS a `string`.  When you parse it off using the `QueryString` object it returns a string as well.  Can you post your code that is parsing off the `querystring`?

If your code is not checking for an empty value or doing a `TryParse` then you could have errors.  Keep in mind anyone can manipulate this data so you should be verifying that it is of the proper type.

Eg:

```
Dim yourValue As Double = 0
If Double.TryParse(Request.QueryString("id"), yourValue) = False Then
    ShowError("Invalid id supplied.")
    Return
End If
```